# Admob cordova plugin build error visual studio

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

Iam trying to convert an existing Ionic app into the visual studio cordova environment.  Iam trying to add the admob plugin to it, i have tried several git repos. But whenever i build the project it fails.

Any one come across this and know of a fax/work around.

Error Messages on build:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       cmd: Command failed with exit code 1    PdyVS1  C:\dev2\PdyVS1\PdyVS1\EXEC  1


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command "platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat" exited with code 2.   PdyVS1  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets   336
```

Cheers

Comment: If you get any error messages include them in your question. This should help people answer

Comment: My bet is that the plugin is incompatible with the version of Cordova that your project is targeting. Can you make sure that you're either targeting 5.4.1 out 6?

Comment: Downloaded the version from git rather than the vs2015 vrsion. Worked fine.

Comment: Can anyone update info for VS 2017? Can't get it to work. Which versions of various plugins work together?